# MapDrive via GPP with credentials

Tags: network-shares, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server

At work, one users from a specific domain (and forest) used to map netword drive via script (specified in ScriptPath attributes). All network drives are mapped via GPP, except one. Actually this networks drive is mapped with a command like `net use \\standalonesrv\share password /user:WORKGROUP\username`

This network drive needs alternate credentials to be mapped, it is an internal application wich can't be joined to an ActiveDirectory.  (same credentials for a group of users)

**I know that it is unsecure (and it is why i need to change that).**

Using alternate credentials are greyed out since a while via GPP : https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/2962486/ms14-025-vulnerability-in-group-policy-preferences-could-allow-elevati

How can i achieve to map network drive drive via GPO in a more secure way than via `net use` ?

By advance, thanks.